# how to refresh UI5 table from JSON Model after database insert using xsjs

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5, hana

I have a requirement to insert new records into db using UI5.Now I  have a table displayed already in UI5 that shows existing data in that database table.I have used xsjs as the backend service and used JSON Model to display the UI5 table.Now I have to insert new records into the table . I have a xsjs at the backend which takes care of the insert in db table but even though the db table gets updated, my ui5 table data remains the same until I reload the page.I cannot directly update the UI5 table from front end using model array.push form values because there are certain meta parameters like updated by(current user ) and updated on (timestamp) fields which need to have values from live update.Please tell me how to update the UI5 table on record insertion ,without reloading the page.

Comment: You can update a JSONModel with data from the backend by calling `loadData`. You can check the documentation for details.: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData

Comment: I have checked that already but however, the table does not get refreshed..Do we have any way to refresh the table without refreshing the page as a whole?

Comment: Try to refresh model oModel.refresh();

Answer (score 0):

Every minute or a period of time you could try to get the delta and update your data accordingly and then refresh the model. You can use OData filters http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/ to determine which records was generated during that period of time. Fields to be filtered depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way (in cnontroller):

1. Create getData() method which will trigger GET request to your xsjs
2. create onGetDataComplete(data) which will create and set the model to your table and executed as a callback of your success on getData()
3. Create putData() which will post to your xsjs
4. Create onPutDataComplete() which will be executed as a call back of your success on putData(). In this method you can call getData() again and you will have your updated stuff.